# Best way to compare the content of two flat files

Tags: c#, sql-server, file, compare

We are having lot of `|` (pipe) separated flat files, which we process on daily basis in SQL Server using a SSIS package. Each flat file are divided into header section, content section and footer section. We regularly get newer version of the same files. We are trying to implement file comparison functionality between two versions of same file, to reduce the load of processing.

Which method will be more efficient ?

1. Storing both versions of same file into separate SQL Server tables with checksum column and filter out rows for which checksum values are not matching.
2. Implementing the similar checksum logic in C# or any other comparison algorithm available in C#.

You may suggest any other new algorithm to achieve the same.

Comment: can you paste little content of the files?

Comment: did this work out for you Murali?

Comment: Verson 1 File:
H1|11|111111111111111|          |111111111|AAAAAAA|2222222|20160205|
H2|33|test test|2|2|2|2|2|2|3|20160205
H3|33|44|55|55|66|77|

Verson 2 File:
H1|11|55555555555|          |7777777|bbbbbbbb|666666|20160205|
H2|33|test test|2|2|2|2|2|2|3|20160205
H3|33|44|55|55|66|77|

Comment: @MuraliDharDarshan it would be awesome if you tell us what eventually worked for you. We are in a similar situation and looking at what is the recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are loading both of these into SQL Server already, then a fast way would be using [`EXCEPT()` or `INTERSECT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql) depending on what your goal is.

```
select * from version2
except
select * from version1
```

This would return rows in `version2` that didn't exactly match the rows in `version1`. You could also only select a single column if you want to compare off that.

Comment: I think the question is about what method to use. The OP is asking if they should load both versions in different SQL tables and use SQL queries to do the diff OR is it more efficient to do the diff using some custom code separately. After the diff is obtained, they want to use only the records that different to update the existing SQL master table. Do you have recommendations for that?